# Fullcalendar - Vertical resources, horizontal days

Tags: javascript, php, fullcalendar

I would like to know, if there is any way to create a calendar with Fullcalendar in such format:

```
               Resource A   Resource B   Resource C

Apr. 26

Apr. 27

Apr. 28

Apr. 29
```

The timeline view is similar to that, but not exactly what I need. It's very important to have a calendar that could manage events like this.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: there's no option for it. You'd have to create a custom view (see https://fullcalendar.io/docs/custom-view-with-js) which is not a simple task. Or you could request it as a feature (https://fullcalendar.io/requesting-features) if there isn't such a request already, but I imagine it would take a bit of time to implement. Your only other option is using https://fullcalendar.io/docs/vertical-resource-view, which gets both the dates _and_ the resources shown vertically. not really what you wanted but it's a compromise option.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the initial question was about something which can not be done in this plugin

Answer (score 2):

Yes. This is a workaround. Try to declare a custom view like this:

```
$(function() {

  // You should change dynamically the min/maxtime
  // settings of your custom view when switching
  // between months.
  // https://fullcalendar.io/docs/dynamic-options

  var getDaysInMonth = function() {
    var d = new Date();
    var year = d.getYear();
    var month = d.getMonth() + 1;
    return new Date(year, month, 0).getDate();
  };

  var getMonthDay = function() {
    var d = new Date();
    return d.getDate();
  };

  var getMinTime = function() {
    var days = getMonthDay() - 1;
    var time = "-" + days + ".00:00:00";
    return time;
  };

  var getMaxTime = function() {
    var days = getDaysInMonth() - getMonthDay() + 1;
    var time = days + ".00:00:00";
    return time;
  };

  $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    defaultView: 'agendaMonth',
    groupByResource: true,
    header: {
      left: 'prev,next today',
      center: 'title',
      right: 'agendaMonth,listThreeDay,agendaWeek,month'
    },
    views: {
      listThreeDay: {
        type: 'list',
        duration: {
          days: 31
        }
      },
      agendaMonth: {
        type: 'agendaDay',
        minTime: getMinTime(),
        maxTime: getMaxTime(),
        slotDuration: '24:00:00',
        slotLabelFormat: [
          'MMMM YYYY', // top level of text
          'D' // lower level of text
        ],
        buttonText: 'custom agenda'
      },      
    },    
    resources: [
      { id: 'a', title: 'Room A' },
      { id: 'b', title: 'Room B' }
    ],
    events: 'https://fullcalendar.io/demo-events.json?with-resources=2'
  });

});
```

Working demo: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/jKQvLx

Comment: I couldn't make it work with multiple dates. By any chance you have a implementation of code with multiple day events?

Comment: @MonkeyDLuffy What do you mean by "multiple day events"? Based on the codepen demo, what do you want to achieve? (since in that demo there are several day events showing up...)

Comment: What i want to achieve is listing events that goes more than one day. For example, a job starts at 24 October and ends 29 October. As far as i understand from the codepen demo it's only shows hourly events. https://i.imgur.com/ZbO4kXT.jpg

Comment: @makoredo you find a way to achieve it ?