# FullCalendar - Change x and y axis with resource groups and day

Tags: fullcalendar, fullcalendar-scheduler

Hi there my good fellows,

What i want to achieve is, list the resources on the x axis and list the dates on the y axis. I have spent some time with [Vertical Resource Demo](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/vertical-resource-custom-demo) but faild to get a look like this.

I've got involed to the creating custom view with js classes thing but couldn't even list the dates. Could anybody guide to me any resource or help me with any code sample?

[image: fullcalendar custom timeline view with resource group]
Dates on y axis will long last for two months.

Thank you all

Comment: in this view, each vertical column is a day (split into resources, optionally, or alternatively resources split into days). The horizontal rows can only be times of the day. It's just a limitation of the view type. As far as I know there currently isn't a view type which would meet your requirement. You could potentially make a feature request, or try to implement your own custom view (see the documentation for details).

Comment: Can you please post your JS code? What's the main problem here? You just can't get days on the Y axis?

Comment: Found this answer right know, but i guess it has some issues with displaying events more than one day.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50213764/fullcalendar-vertical-resources-horizontal-days